# Google Picasa Web Albums API - Add comment returning 501 response code

Tags: android, api, picasa

I had integrated Google Picasa Web Albums API for showing photos from picasa album, Now i am trying to [add comment](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#AddComments) on those photos, here i am facing weird issue i.e. first comment working fine but when i am going to comment same photo for second time, api returning me 501 response code.

Log : 
12-09 23:56:13.102: E/Volley(9596): [332] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 501 for http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user//albumid/5915421892796637153/photoid/5915421896694697746?alt=json&access_token=

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same issue when uploading photos. First one works fine, second one breaks with 501 error. Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra "/" in the URL, ...feed/api/user//<-- perhaps this is the error?

(I would have left this as a comment but I don't have the score!!)